# Reasons for transactions not getting confirmed

Tags: transactions

What are possible reasons for a transaction not getting confirmed even after it is successfully executed.
I'm following server-side signing and using the `push_transaction` API to execute the transaction. It works well. But sometimes, the executed transaction is not getting confirmed in the block.

I'm aware that the `transaction_id` returned from the `push_transaction` API response is generated logically and it doesn't guarantee the block confirmation.

Is trying to get the transaction details using the returned `transaction_id` until a successful attempt is a right way to confirm the same? Or is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 0):

please read the FAQs from the transaction section of the EOSIO Developer Portal
https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/faq/index/#transactions

it should give you more information you want to know about this topic.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to say the reason why this happen without additional information. But keeping in mind the nature of blockchain I want to say that it's a normal case. Blockchain is distributed network and sometimes transaction might be lost. Transaction ID is just a transaction hash and it is not proving that transaction is accepted by the network. That's why it's very important to check that transaction was accepted in the block before treating it as a completed.

Comment: This information is already written in the question itself

Comment: @Muhzin you've asked about other solutions. I explained, that there is no other solutions because of blockchain distributed nature. Why minus?!